# Qt c++ как запустить программу если это невозможно?

Tags: c++, qt

Написал программу через Qt Creator. Если я в qt creator запускаю ее, она нормально собирается и работает, но открываю папку где у мене exe файл программы собрался, открываю exe, и полетели  ошибки...

Там не хватает библиотек Qt, я взял просто с папки bin все библиотеки Qt которые там есть и скопировал в папку с exe, теперь ему не хватает каких то плагинов, я так понял мне надо весь Qt в 3 гигабайта скопировать в папку с exe программой чтоб она заработала?

Как запустить программу на Qt?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Answer (score 2):

Используйте утилиту `windeployqt` - она скопирует необходимые файлы.

Для сборки архива с автономной программой нужно вызвать `windeployqt` из выбранного комплекта `Qt` в папке с вашим `exe`

Для примера `Qt` установлен в директории `c:/Qt/` и выбран комплект `Qt5.15.2 / Visual Studio 2019 x64`, а скомпилированная программа расположена в `c:/project/build/release/`.

Тогда вам потребуется выполнить последовательность команд

```
set QT_PATH=c:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin
set EXE_PATH=c:\project\build\release

@rem добавим путь до windeployqt в PATH
set PATH=%QT_PATH%;%PATH%

@rem перейдем в папку с программой
cd %EXE_PATH%

@rem запустим копирование библиотек
windeployqt .\
```

В результате в папку с программой скопируется около 50-70 мегабайт.